# Files Compression Techniques in PHP

Tags: php, compression

We are making one web site on which site users, can upload the data. 
Data will be in any format. means it can any media file or any image file or any video file or any document file.
Any compression technique for any data.
We are using PHP. 
Anything you suggestion by which whatever the data gone on server, it should be in minimum size.
Any suggestion technique. But first rule is, data should be compressed maximum.
**And it will be greatly appreciated if you can suggest me with out any software, use by just coding.**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot compress most of media data as it's already compressed. Why not just to buy another HDD?

Answer (score 1):

You can compress it (create a tar file for example) when moving the file from its temp upload location to a more permanent place on disk. However the file types you are talking about are binary files which don't always compress very much. Second no one compression scheme will result in the best results for all file types.

Comment: In this site, user can also see that file which they had uploaded. Now if i try to make any tar or zip file, then when user want to see that data, then i have to convert also in the original format which will take many times.

Comment: I would be very concerned about security. If the user can both upload any file and see it (I assume you mean click a link). there is little stopping them from uploading arbitrary code which will be run by your server. Safety says that you should at least change the name and prevent any script from executing.

Answer (score 0):

there is a way to compress files for different type of files there are tools e.g. for media data FFmpeg the good solution.